# DI and base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've created simple **asp.net core** application by typical example and it works as expected. Then I've added configuration support through **appsettings.json** like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController: BaseController
{
private IConfiguration _configuration = null;
public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
//some actions here
}
```

and it worked too.
But now I wanted to have a realization of `Configuration` in my base class(`BaseController`) so all derived controllers will have access to it.
Nothing hard, I thought and rewritten to this:
public class

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController: BaseController
{
//some actions here
}

public class BaseController: ControllerBase
{
        private IConfiguration _configuration = null;
        public IConfiguration Configuration
        {
            get
            {
                return _configuration;
            }
        }

        public BaseController(IConfiguration configuration = null)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
}
```

and while this code successfully compiles with default value of parameter in base class constructor, `Configuration` is always `null`.

What I'm doing wrong and is it able now to make this work in clean way?

Comment: You shouldn't inject `IConfiguration`in the first place. Use the `IOptions<T>` pattern instead

Comment: Anyway the question remains same: how to initialize DI-resource in base class without touching anything in derived? All solutions below actually ignore initialization in base class and require changes in derived.

Comment: You can't, that's the point of constructor injection (only one supported by the default IoC framework). You inject Ioptions classes in the concrete controllers and only shared options in base classes. Your design seems flawed, to inject generic configuration when each controller needs its own

Comment: btw. Constructor injection dictates **mandatory** dependencies, as in "without it, the class won't/can't work". So anything you inject to it is **absolutely required**. And when your base class doesn't need any specific (shared) options, then don't inject it in there, since its obviously not required. And if its a shared option that even the base class and every deriving class absolutely requires, then it also needs to be defined in the constructor (since its mandatory)

Comment: Also Dependency Injection (or DI/IoC Container to be more specific) are no compiler black magic, all it does is what you'd usually do when `new`ing a class, except that the IoC/DI framework takes the work for you to initialize, pass and manage the lifetime of the dependencies

Comment: Sorry for offtopic here, but will `IOptions<T>` handle configuration file change?

Comment: No, but `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` will, if the configuration file is marked as `reloadOnChange` (on .AddJsonFile call) is set to `true`: [Reload configuration data with IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot)

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the `IConfiguration` parameter from the sub class constructor to the base class constructor.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected IConfiguration _configuration;

    public BaseClass(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

Note that the instance variable `IConfiguration` of the base class needs to be protected if you want to be able to access it from a sub class.

```
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration) { }
}
```

By adding the `base(configuration)`, you call the base class constructor and passes the `configuration` parameter to it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all. Mark Your base class `abstract` With a `protected` constructor. Use the `base` keyword from you child class to instansiate the private field IConfiguration in Your base class.

```
   public class MyController(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration) {}

    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
       protected BaseClass(IConfiguration configuration) { _configuration = configuration; }
    }
```